# How to Revert VS Code run and debug configurations to default

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code

I typically only ran Python and C++ code. When running Python Code, it would drop down a simply menu, such as this.

[image: img]

It would drop this down then you would click enter and boom it would run

But then I randomly ran a `console.log("Hello World")` JavaScript program. It dropped down a menu and I selected something like "Node.js" or whatever.

Anyway now when I go to run code, it opens in something called the "*JavaScript Debug Terminal*". The code never ran and you just had to manually open the file and run it. Later I went to the *run and debug* page and added a configuration to a `launch.json` file, where I added a Python Config:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when I run Python Code it runs in something called the "*Python Debug Console*". Can someone tell me how to revert this to how it was in the factor settings

Comment: remove your `launch.json` file

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're running the python file in debug mode. If you want to run python normally you can right-click anywhere in the file and select `run python file in terminal`.

[image]

For more information on running python files, you can look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial.

Comment: that works thanks. but i want to revert to how it was out of the box