# VS Code Python January 2024 "Run and Debug" how to re-enable "select a debug configuration"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I start a Python project and hit `F5` / `Run and Debug` nothing happens. This was not always the case, but I think I may have accidentally changed a setting in VS Code to cause this.

The previous behavior was that the following list of debug config options would appear, and I would choose the option I wanted:

```
Python File
Module
Remote Attach
Attach using Process ID
Django
FastAPI
FLask 
Pyramid
```

[image]

Now, the options don't appear, and the debug session does not start - nothing happens.

I do not have a launch.json in any of my project folders, and I'm wondering how to get back those options without creating a launch.json.

Searched for launch.json, and there is none. I did not create one previously.
I have tried restarting vscode, and restarting my laptop.
I have look for vs code debug settings to change - none seem appropriate for fixing this

if I select `Show all automatic debug configurations`, I get only two options:
Node.js..
Python Debugger...

[image]

This post is similar, but the solution given bypasses getting the  list of debug configurations to select from
[How to Revert VS Code run and debug configurations to default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814513/how-to-revert-vs-code-run-and-debug-configurations-to-default)

Comment: @starball no I don't have a launch.json file. I don't think I had one before the issue started either.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if you're looking for [these bits of the Python extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/204bcbc2ce18229309471d459dc6865e2d8313e9/src/client/debugger/extension/configuration/debugConfigurationService.ts#L125), it's [moved over](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python-debugger/blob/1cce48cee0741f84f909e5cf897cfdaa9afa55fc/src/extension/debugger/configuration/debugConfigurationService.ts#L109) to the debugpy extension now. In case you missed the announcement, it's at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86#_python-debugger-extension-installed-by-default. See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/22502 and the following https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/22738.

Make sure [the `ms-python.debugpy` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.debugpy) is installed (it should be installed automatically as part of the Python extension update), and that it's *enabled*. Then press F5, and when prompted to select a debugger, select "Python Debugger", and then you'll see the options you want.