# Visual Studio Code debugging with python extension Version v2024.0.0 not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am working in Visual Studio Code (Version 1.86, details below) in Windows 10 (Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045) with Python. Since the last update of the Python extension (Version 2024.0.0) the debugging does not work for me. I tried the 'F5' button, but also the menu 'Run' > 'Start Debugging'. Neither works.

Then I tried Version v2023.22.1 for the Python extension and it works again. I assume that this does not occur for everyone. May question is, it that a bug of the current version, or am I doing something wrong? Did a default setting change, is it a incompatibility with my system or other extension?

```
VSC Version details:
Version: 1.86.0 (user setup)
Commit: 05047486b6df5eb8d44b2ecd70ea3bdf775fd937
Date: 2024-01-31T10:28:19.990Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26495564
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Comment: Bugs should be reported to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues. Stack Overflow isn't the site for that.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I can see, that bugs should be reported somewhere else. The question is, it this a bug? Or is it a fail by the user (me). However, I will keep your comment in mind, when I have more information about the problem. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug bits of the Microsoft Python extension have been extracted to [the Microsoft Python DebugPy extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.debugpy). You can find the announcement [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86#_python-debugger-extension-installed-by-default). Make sure the `ms-python.debugpy` extension is installed (it should be installed automatically as part of the Python extension update), and that it's *enabled*. If I remember correctly, it was disabled for me by default for some reason.

You might need to create a launch config to use F5 to launch. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77937940/11107541.

Comment: Thx a lot. That helped me to understand why it did not work anymore. I had the Python Debugger already installed and it was also active. However, I noticed now, that debugging was only possible via the Button in the Top right corner ( _Python Debugger: Debug Python File_). But it was not possible by pressing "_F5_" or clicking on "_Run_" > "_Start Debugging_".

To make this work again, I had to click on "_Run_" > "_Add Configuration_" which created a file "launch.json". Now I can use "_F5_" or "_Run_" > "_Start Debugging_". So, problem fixed. Thx again starball.

Comment: This also helped me (thanks!), but only after I noticed @martin_ai 's comment about F5 not working by default. starball , it would be great if you updated your answer with that