# Default VS Code debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I create a new Python file (Mac) in VS Code and try to run it, a window at the top pops up to select a debugger ([debugger dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Hzk.png)). I can click on Python Debugger, then I can run the program with no problems, and when I run it again, this msg doesn't appear.

Alternatively, if I click on "Install an Extension", a list pops up. I've selected "Python Debugger" (many times) but I get the same window popping up. [select debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUVjJ.png)

I've seen references to .vscode files. I searched my drive, and I have dozens of them. Are there settings in VS Code where I can tell it to always use the Python Debugger? If so, could you please explain how to do this?

I don't know what I did because this message never appeared until recently. It always used the Python Debugger.

Comment: do you use CodeRunner or F5/launch config

Comment: Are you looking for [`launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)?

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77940714/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77930551/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You could [read document about VSCode Python Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations).

To initialize debug configurations, first select the Run view in the sidebar:

[image]

If you don't yet have any configurations defined, you'll see a button to Run and Debug and a link to create a configuration (launch.json) file:

[image]

To generate a launch.json file with Python configurations, do the following steps:

1. Select the create a launch.json file link (outlined in the image
   above) or use the Run > Open configurations menu command.
2. Select Python Debugger from the debugger options list.
3. A configuration menu will open from the Command Palette allowing you
   to choose the type of debug configuration you want to use for our
   Python project file. If you want to debug a single Python script,
   select Python File in the Select a debug configuration menu that
   appears.

[image]

You could also delete the `launch.json` file in `.vscode` folder and create a new one to set it.