# Running Python program on VSCode. Won't print output. Complains about debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am running a Python Project on VsCode.  For a previous assignment in the course, VSCode asked me to choose a debugger and then ran the program, showing the output

For this one, it only displayed this message on the terminal, and did not show any program output, even though the program contained print statements. I am unsure what the problem is.

```
 PS C:\Users\geniu\OneDrive\GW\Spring 2024\CSCI 6511>  c:; cd 
'c:\Users\geniu\OneDrive\GW\Spring 2024\CSCI 6511'; & 
'c:\Users\geniu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe' 
'c:\Users\geniu\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32- 
x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '62314' '--' 
'c:\Users\geniu\OneDrive\GW\Spring 2024\CSCI 6511\Project2.py'
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/77930551/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77940714/11107541

Comment: why do you have spaces in file paths